# Mongoose get highest values by key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    key: String,
    value: Number
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I have entries like this (i'm collecting different stats)

```
var entry1 = {
    key: "subscribers",
    value: 100
}
var entry2 = {
    key: "online",
    value: 105
}
```

I'm trying to get the all time high values for each key.
Right now I have this:

```
var now = new Date();
var startOfToday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
db.getConnection().model("MaxValue").aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        createdAt: {
            $gte: startOfToday
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "value": { "$max": "$value" },
    }
}], function(err,result) {
    resolve(result)
})
```

But I want to get the created date also for that value because I want to know when that value was recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so easy because **$max** is an accumulator so you can't just take this date directtly to the result. Therefore we have to add few more pipeline stages. Fortunately we have **$addToSet** operator so we can add custom transformations to each group.

So after grouping, each group should still contain dates paired with values. Then we do the unwinding to process each item separately. Next we can set new field which discriminates if such document contains max value in group. **$cmp** operator will set this field to 0 if strings are equal. Finally in last stage we can filter out documents without max value.

```
db.maxValues.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "value": { "$max": "$value" },
            "values": { "$addToSet" : { "value": "$value", "createdAt": "$createdAt" }}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$values"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "key": "$_id",
            "value": 1,
            "createdAt": "$values.createdAt",
            "compared": { "$cmp": ["$value", "$values.value"] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "compared": 0 }
    }
])
```

Comment: sorry for this long delay. this was the answer. thank you